# How to sum key value of all documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am just new to Mongo DB an facing problem in summation of the key value of all documents...

Here I am providing the sample data of Mongo DB-

```
{ _id: 1, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 50 }    

{ _id: 2, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-01T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 100 }    

{ _id: 3, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 25 }    

{ _id: 4, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-11T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 125 }    

{ _id: 5, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-11-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 25 }
```

All i want is to get the total value of key "amount", like for example-
`50+100+25+125+25`

Comment: read about aggregation and the $sum modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like this:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate({ $group: { _id : null, sum : { $sum: "$amount" } } });
```

More details about **aggregation** can be found at [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/), and more details about **sum** can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html)

Comment: you'r welcome. I updated the answer with new link. Please don't forget to mark as answer. Happy coding.

Comment: I am greatful for your support